# Trying to format a return statement in python

Tags: python-3.x

```
import random

def main():
    print('MILES\t KILOMETERS')
    print('-----\t ----------') 
    m = float
    k = float
    for limit in range (1,11): #Keeps the table from going on forever
      final = randyGen(m, k)    #Arguments to function
      print(final)


def randyGen(miles, kilos): #Function to produce miles and kilometers
    miles = random.randint(10,60)
    kilos = miles * 1.60934
    return miles, kilos



main()

input('\n\nPress ENTER to exit.')
```

I need the miles statement to stop at 2 decimal points and the kilometers to stop at 5. I've attempted to add format to randyGen as well as to the main function and neither worked.

Comment: Unpack returned tuple with `final_miles, final_kilos = randyGen(...)` and then format each number in an appropriate way with `"{:.2f} {:.2f}".format(final_miles, final_kilos)`

Comment: @yeputons Thanks! This worked

Answer (score 0):

I made a slight change to your output

```
import random

def main():
    print('MILES\t KILOMETERS')
    print('-----\t ----------') 
    m = float
    k = float
    for limit in range (1,11): #Keeps the table from going on forever
      final = randyGen(m, k)    #Arguments to function
      print('Km: %3.5f' %final)


def randyGen(miles, kilos): #Function to produce miles and kilometers
    miles = random.randint(10,60)
    print('Miles: %2.2f' %miles)
    kilos = miles * 1.60934
    return kilos

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

That results

```
MILES    KILOMETERS
-----    ----------
Miles: 46.00
Km: 74.02964
Miles: 16.00
Km: 25.74944
Miles: 12.00
Km: 19.31208
Miles: 20.00
Km: 32.18680
Miles: 27.00
Km: 43.45218
Miles: 12.00
Km: 19.31208
Miles: 39.00
Km: 62.76426
Miles: 39.00
Km: 62.76426
Miles: 38.00
Km: 61.15492
Miles: 30.00
Km: 48.28020
```